# Mouse right click is not working in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have scene with the input field in unity.I am just trying to paste the copied code into that input field.I can paste it through `cmd+v` but unable to get panel with a paste option while right clicking.Is there any way to have access that panel after mouse right click in unity.[image]

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Unity won't show you the OS-specific context menu in-game. Don't forget that Unity is cross-platform. If you want a context menu on right-click then you will need to create this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation@Kwinten,What do you expect to happen?->I just wants to paste copied data without cmd+v into the input field.

Comment: As pointed by Kwinten, you will need to create your own menu to copy and paste. You can use GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer to get or set the text of the clipboard by code.